# How to convert custom query to laravel 5?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I am fetching order_id, created_at date, transaction_amount from transaction table. I got some records with order_id, its created_at date and transaction_amount. Now I want the sum of transaction_amount column. I tried following query on db directly which working well, but I am unable to write same query in laravel.

```
select sum(transaction_amount) from (
select order_id, max(created_at), transaction_amount
from transactions
WHERE user_id =100 AND accounting_type = "Debit"
group by order_id
limit 500 ) as transactions
```

I tried this way but still not working

```
$sql = "select sum(transaction_amount) from 
                ('select order_id, max(created_at), transaction_amount
                from transactions
                WHERE user_id =100 
                group by order_id
                limit 500') as transactions";
        $result = \DB::select( \DB::raw($sql));
```

Comment: Where is your `user_id` column ? If in transaction table then  you are not selecting so how can you use it with where ?

Comment: The `DB:raw()` should do just fine. What exactly doesn't work? Dou you get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let break down your query:
Main query

```
SELECT
SUM( transaction_amount )
FROM
    (...) AS transactions
```

This just used for summarize. And your sub query:

```
        SELECT
            order_id,
            MAX( created_at ),
            transaction_amount
        FROM
            transactions
        WHERE
            user_id = 100
            AND accounting_type = "Debit"
        GROUP BY
            order_id LIMIT 500
```

For the sub query, the Laravel query builder should be:

```
use DB;

$result = DB::table('table')
->select(DB::raw("order_id, MAX(created_at), transaction_amount"))
->where("user_id", "=", 100)
->where("accounting_type", "=", "Debit")
->groupBy("order_id")
->limit(500)
->get(); // this will return Laravel Collection (Illuminate\Support\Collection)
```

Laravel Collection has `sum` method so you can call it

```
$result->sum('transaction_amount');
```

For more information please read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) and [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sum) Laravel documentation.

Comment: I wonder `user_id` in line `->where("user_id", "=", 100)` will work ? From where it will come there ?

Comment: I think `DB::table()` rather have to be `DB::table('transactions')` in order to work.

Comment: column in `WHERE` clause of SQL doesnt mean has to be exist in `SELECT` clause just try it. But may be what do you mean is while using  `GROUP BY`. Columns used in `GROUP BY` cluse should exist in `SELECT` clause. CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

I think your `$sql` variable has to contain only the sub query from your `FROM`.

The `table()` method of the Laravel QueryBuilder is the "*equivalent*" of `FROM` statement in SQL, it is here that you put your sub query.

Try

```
$sql = 'select order_id, max(created_at), transaction_amount
            from transactions
            WHERE user_id =100 
            group by order_id
            limit 500';

$result = \DB::table(\DB::raw($sql))->sum('transaction_amount');
```

And instead, if you want a parrallel with the `select()` method you tried to use:

```
$result = \DB::table(\DB::raw($sql))->select(\DB::raw('sum(transaction_amount) as sum'))->get();
```